# Möbius function tag ambiguity

Tags: discussion, tagging, tag-management

The tag for [mobius-function](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mobius-function) currently reads "questions on the Möbius function $μ(n)$, an arithmetic function used in number theory", which is true, but it's also a specific case of Möbius function in order theory that's used often in combinatorics. There is a tag for [mobius-inversion](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mobius-inversion), which is the main reason for its use in combinatorics, but if it's meant that number theory questions use the former tag, and combinatorics questions the latter, I feel like that's not a precise way of separating them, especially since I seem some order theory questions in the first (I just asked a question on it, and I used the first tag since my question didn't actually mention inversion). Should the description for the first tag be edited, or should they be separated in a clearer way?

Comment: Without having looked in detail, I'd generalize the description of the tag m-f, and we might just get rid of m-i.

Comment: Not sure many people use those tags. To me the useful category would be "applications in arithmetic of $\zeta(s)$, Dirichlet series and analytic-number-theory"

Comment: I don't see why the description of m-f couldn't be used for all instances of the function, since people can also use number-theory or something to specialize.  m-i probably could still exist, as not all uses of m-f are necessarily m-i (especially if they are homework problems), but both sides of this could be argued.